# Group presentation in the category of finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, definitions, presentations-of-groups

Context: I'm trying to deal with presentations in the framework of Gonthier et al. formalization of the group theory in the proof assistant Coq. It was used to machine check the Feit-Thompson odd order theorem. In this formalisation, all groups are assumed to be **finite** and it would be a lot of work to remove the assumption. Actually, roughly speaking, all **sets** are assumed to be finite.

Summary question: Is there a finite group $G$ with a presentation where one of the relation can be deduced by the kownledge that $G$ is finite.

I'd like to define a presentation as follows:
Let $I$ be a finite set and $R$ be a finite collection of word in $I$. For any finite group $G$, and any map $g:I\to G$, I say that $(g, R)$ is a presentation of $G$ iff

1. $\{g(i) | i \in I\}$ generate $G$;
2. The relations $R$ holds in $G$, that is for any $r\in R$, then $\prod_{i : r} g(i) = 1$;
3. For any **finite** group $H$ and any map $h : I \to H$, if $\prod_{i : r} h(i) = 1$ holds for any $r\in R$, then there is a group morphism $\phi : G \to H$ such that $\phi(g(i))=h(i)$ for all $i\in I$.

Allow me to stress once again that the universal properties of condition 3. only holds for finite groups.

My question is: does this coincide whith the usual definition of presentation ?

In particular, I'd like to prove that any word in the $\{g(i)\}$ is $1$ if it can be written as a concatenation of relators or their conjugates. But in order to do that I usually need to consider the quotient of the free group by the normal subgroup generated by the relators. However to prove that this quotient is finite, I need the exact propoerty I'm trying to prove.

Here is a rephrasing of my question:

Suppose that a finite group $H$ verify some relations $R$ ($R$ finite) on some generators $h_i$ ($I$ finite). Suppose that a word $w$ in the $h_i$ is equal to $1$ in $H$ but can't be written as a concatenation of the conjugate of the relators in $R$. Does there always exists a **finite** group $H'$ such that $H$ is a homomorphic image of $H'$ but $w$ is not $1$ in $H'$ ?

**[edit]** added ($R$ and $I$ finite in the above rephasing).

Comment: The groups satisfying such a property are the quotient of the group $H$ defined by this presentation (in the usual sense) by normal subgroups that are contained in the finite residual (=intersection of finite index subgroups of $H$).

Comment: Your rephrased question is equivalent to whether every group is residually finite (take $H=1$).

Comment: @YCor: So I guess my question is : is any finite group residually finite. Wikipedia claims it is. Do you have any reference for that ? I'm coming from algebraic combinatorics and I'm mostly knowledgable in Coxeter groups where it goes to group theory.

Comment: It seems that I've found what I need in https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group

Comment: No, you seem to be asking whether every group is residually finite, which is false. According to your definition, a (standard) presentation of a nontrivial  group with no nontrivial finite quotients would be a presentation of the trivial group.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Sorry I don't get it. In my definition I'm assuming that G itself is finite.

Comment: @hivert In Derek Holt's comment $G$ is the trivial group. They're saying that there are finitely presented groups with no nontrivial finite quotients (I do not know much group theory, so I don't know any such example)

Comment: I had missed that the set $I$ is finite. So the first question is indeed whether every finitely presented group is residually finite. But in the "rephrasing", OP doesn't assume $R$ nor the indexing set of the family $(h_i)$ to be finite, so it's indeed equivalent to asking whether every group is residually finite.

Comment: @YCor: I should have written one or two more finite in the rephrasing ! Anyway having an infinite presentation (either in the generator or the relations) for a finite group seems to be silly to me...

Comment: @hivert but the core of the issue in your question lies in presentations of the trivial group. So no, it's definitely not silly and let me give an example: generators $h_n=1$ ($n\ge 0$), with relators $h_{n+1}^2=h_n$ $\forall n\ge 0$ and $h_0^2=1$. Then such relators in a finite group force $h_0=1$ (and, by induction force $h_n=1$ for all $n$). But $h_0=1$ does not formally follow from these relators, since it is easy to find an infinite group with such elements with these relations, but $h_0\neq 1$.

Comment: Fair point. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A well-known example, due to G. Higman,  of an infinite finitely presented group with no nontrivial finite quotients   is $$G = \langle a,b,c,d \mid a^{-1}ba=b^2,b^{-1}cb=c^2,c^{-1}dc=d^2,d^{-1}ad=a^2 \rangle.$$
Proving it has no nontrivial finite quotients is elementary and a nice exercise. The idea is to prove that $f(a) < f(b) < f(c) < f(d) < f(a)$, where $f(g)$ is the smallest prime factor of the order of $g$ in a candidate for a nontrivial finite quotient.

Proving it infinite can be done using the fact that the group is an amalgamated product of two HNN extensions: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394006) for example.

But according to your definition of a presentation of a finite group, this presentation would define the trivial group, because there are no other finite homomorphic images of $G$.

So the answer to your question is no, your definition of a presentation of a finite group is not equivalent to the standard notion of a group presentation.